# Python reading csv files, assign each line to a variable

Tags: python, csv

Currently i have problems with the formatting of the read data. Instead of returning a list for each row, the code returns a list with each index being a column.

The csv file looks like this:

```
2020-08-26 00:00:00,2020-08-27 00:00:00,2020-08-28 00:00:00 
1505,1515,1527
```

And the code is this:

```
    with open("csvfile.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        for i, line in enumerate(reader):
            print(line[0].format(i, line))
```

Current output:

```
2020-08-26 00:00:00
1505
```

Desired output:

```
['2020-08-26 00:00:00','2020-08-27 00:00:00','2020-08-28 00:00:00'] 
[1505, 1515, 1527]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import csv

with open("csvfile.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

We could even make it a one-liner:

```py
import csv

with open("csvfile.csv", "r") as f:
    [print(line) for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")]
```

And if you just have these 2 lines and want each of them in a variable you can use:

```py
import csv

with open("csvfile.csv", "r") as f:
    x, y = tuple(csv.reader(f, delimiter=","))
# Use x and y, preferably outside of the `with` statement
# as we can already close the file
```

Comment: Format seems right, is there an easy way of assigning each line to a different variable? I want the datetimes to be variable x and integer values to be variable y, both variables in list format.

Comment: Can you try `x, y = tuple(csv.reader(f, delimiter=","))`? I'm not 100% sure if the `tuple` constructor will take the reader but I think it will.

Comment: Thank you, it works, i have tried about 5 different solutions to the same 3 lines of code, none of them worked exactly like i wanted it.

Comment: @LasseFisker Added this part to the question, if your question was solved please mark this answer as the solution so that the question gets marked as solved.